# 'Select All' option in SharePoint 2013 list column filters

Tags: 2013, list, filter

I have SharePoint 2013 list. Need to get **'Select All'** option in list filter (on the **columns**' filters). Currently SP only has 'Clear Filters'.
[image]
The feauture I need is the same as in **Excel Autofilter:**

[image]

What I would need to get is:

1. Click Select All
2. Deselect 1 of the options
   Thus I would have limited my filtered list and would not need to click all items manually.

Answer (score 0):

Clear filters should be the same functionally as select all. With no filters, then all items would be displayed.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
However, after user clicks 'Select All', user is able to Unselect some specific items.
That is what is needed:
1) Select All
2) Deselect specific items (for example, All items except 2 clients: 101 and 102)

Comment: So that will require some jquery, which will likely be somewhat tricky, as it appears that the filter dropdown is being generated dynamically. another possibility is search. This doesn't address the filter issue specifically, but to get every record except "Paul", you could enter the following into the "find a file" search box: -Paul  (the hyphen is "not", so all records except paul)

Comment: Mike2500, thank you for proposition. That may probably help, but only of I fix Search, which apparently only searches Today Created items. Will try to get solution to fix search also here on this site.